# Can i make VBA change it's own code according to the user's needs?

Tags: excel, vba, module, copy, paste

I'm kinda a beginner when it comes to VBA and programming in general so pls try to keep your answers simple. Here is a part of my code:

```
 Sub Makro2()

 Dim XXX As Workbook
 Dim YYY As Workbook
 Set XXX = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\aaa.xlsx")
 Set YYY = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\bbb.xlsx")
 n = XXX.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

XXX.Sheets(1).Activate
Range("A3:A" & n + 1).Select
Selection.Copy
YYY.Sheets(1).Activate
Range("C3").Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

XXX.Sheets(1).Activate
Range("N3:N" & n + 1).Select
Selection.Copy
YYY.Sheets(1).Activate
Range("H3").Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Now this code works for me but my colleague needs Range("N3:N" & n + 1) copied to Range("J3"), not "H3" like me. From what I understand modules are hard-coded so I don't know if this is at all possible. Can I write a piece of code that would alter a previous piece of code depending on what the user wants? If not, is there a way around it?

Comment: You don't write code to alter code, you write code that's parameterized. You could have "N" in some specific "configuration" cell (your colleague's would say "J"), and then the code can read the column from that specific cell and *generate* the address string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider allowing the user to have an input into the macro. This could take the form of an input box, or a specific part of the worksheet (or another worksheet dedicated to that purpose) that would be read into by the macro when launched (whereby a cell could contain the destination cell name, for instance).

So the macro would be the same but it would work differently depending on the user.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. That's exactly what I need.